# What is difference between these 2 Spring IOC injections?

Tags: java, spring

What is difference between these 2 injections ?

```
@Autowired
private DocumentDAO documentDao;

@Resource(name = "documentDao")
private DocumentDAO documentDao;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply, @Autowired(specification in Spring) wires by type and @Resource(specification in JSR-250) wires by name .

But, @Autowired with @Qualifier also can autowire by name as @Resource.

Please take a look below links:

[@Autowire](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

[@Resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-resource-annotation)

[@Spring Injection with @Resource, @Autowired and @Inject](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/08/spring-injection-with-resource-and-autowired/)

Comment: Thanks all for your quick reply, dgregory and rohan, you both on the same line. but @dgregory first :)

Answer (score 9):

By default `@Autowire` inject dependency "by Type". But It can also Inject dependency "by Name" using `@Qualifier` in conjunction with `@Autowire` annotation.

But the key difference is that `@Autowired` is a spring annotation whereas `@Resource` is specified by the JSR-250. So the `@Resource` is part of normal Java on the other side, `@Autowired` is only available by Spring.